# What are the keys to having an active clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What are some of the best things to do for your clan in order for them to be active? There is no way to monitor day-to-day activity, and some of my members are inactive despite us begging them to attack in wars or donate. Is there any good way to get members to be active?

Comment: Do you happen to see your clan members everyday? like at school or work? That helps a lot.

Comment: Some of them. The great majority i don't know.

Comment: oh. than that may be part of the problem them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to having an active clan is personally knowing the members and having other means of communication other than in the game itself.